# ListView event for selected item changed

Tags: events, listview, vb6, selectedindexchanged

Which event occurs when *selected item(or index)* is changed of *ListView*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
```

May be counter-intuitive, but there you go.

Works for selecting with keyboard or mouse, but unlike the ListBox control, doesn't work when setting selected item programmatically.

Comment: It also doesn't allow for unselection of items by clicking in a blank area. For this you need to handle `_Click`.